# Set title size in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I´m working with several types of plots in seaborn reason for which I have to change the font sizes contantly in order to keep it readable. I´m using the plt.rcParams parameter to do it so for most of the options:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 6
plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 12
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 12
plt.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"] = 12
```

But I have not found which is the alias for the title there, the equivalent of "ytick.labelsize" 
I have tried several combinations like:

```
plt.rcParams["title.labelsize"] = 12
```

But have not found the right one.

Comment: `[k for k in plt.rcParams.keys() if 'title' in k]` returns `['axes.titlepad', 'axes.titlesize', 'axes.titleweight', 'figure.titlesize', 'figure.titleweight', 'legend.title_fontsize']`, so it's likely one of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a sample rc file showing all possible options [here.](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file)

I think you are looking for `figure.titlesize`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line to change the title size, Replace `40` by the size of your choice

```
plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 40
```

For an exhaustive list of the allowed parameters, you can read how to [Customize Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)